# Revert Eclipse installation to a previous state via command line

Tags: eclipse

I've installed an update in Eclipse and now it doesn't start with this error:

```
An error has occurred. See the log file ...\.metadata\.log.
```

The last entry in the log is this:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2011-03-10 12:16:22.553
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles
...
```

How can I fix that? Is it possible to revert to some previous configuration from a command line?

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse can't get ahold of any more operating system resources. Close down as many other applications as you can and try to start Eclipse.